# JSR223 Preprocess performance issue Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jsr223

I have an scenario to measure login function performance for that i have used  JSR223 preprocessor to encrypt my password using Javascript its around 2000 Line of code it works fine it encrypts the password successfully,  i can able to login using my script it works fine in small number of users.

If we go for an large volume of users script finish first 3 steps very fast once it reaches JSR223 preprocessor thread it takes long time to process it makes delay in performance test.

Any suggestion to fine tune this process ?

Already i have configured the cache size as 1024 even though it takes long time to execute.

For 600 Users it takes 1hr +++ time to finish the process with 1 Master and  3 slaves environment.

Comment: What is the cpu usage in the machine you run jmeter like? Did you try using multiple jmeter agents?

Comment: I'd like to 2nd satkumar, as I use JSR223 preprocessor with Groovy (2.4.8/ Engine 2.0), and I have script with 140 lines that creates threads pool, and it takes 20-23 seconds just to process before even firing the JSR223 request.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript should be avoided for Load Testing.

The best option is to use:

- Groovy
- Check Cache Compilation Key
- Enter a unique key per Test element

This will make JMeter compile the script leading to most optimal performances, read this for more informations:

- http://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/jmeter_performance_tuning_tips/

If you're looking to learn jmeter correctly, this [book](https://leanpub.com/master-jmeter-from-load-test-to-devops) will help you.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is not the best language to use with JSR223 PreProcessor, it's being run via [Rhino](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Rhino) or [Nashorn](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/nashorn/) engine and your expression is being evaluated all the time from scratch using not very performant way.

According to [JMeter Best Practices](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) it is recommended to use [Groovy](http://www.groovy-lang.org/) scripting engine. Assuming good configuration you will be able to get groovy scripts compiled into native JVM bytecode hence performance will be much higher than for JavaScript.

In order to get Groovy support in Jmeter you just need to

1. Download [groovy-all.jar](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-all)
2. Drop the file to "lib" folder of your JMeter installation
3. Restart JMeter

See [Beanshell vs JSR223 vs Java JMeter Scripting: The Performance-Off You've Been Waiting For!](https://blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-java-jmeter-scripting-its-performance) guide for more detailed explanation and scripting best practices.